# Makefile pattern in reverse order

Tags: makefile

As far as I understood makefile pattern rules, it's always `to: from`, e.g. `%.o: %:c`. However, when I tried making a simple pattern to turn .asm files to .o files, Make seems to interpret these patterns in reverse.

When writing `%.o: %.asm`, and calling it with `make test.asm`, I get `make: Nothing to be done for 'test.asm'.`
However, when I change the rule to `%.asm: %.o` (which would be against anything I have read in any tutorial), my pattern suddenly works.

What am I doing wrong and why does make behave that way? (My current test-Makefile looks like this. It should work, but does not)

```
%.o: %.asm
    echo Doing something
```

Comment: `.o` files don't go *to* `.c` files. So either you typoed your `to: from` example or you have a bit of a disconnect there. (I know you have your answer already but I figured I'd point that detail of the post out.)

Comment: I know that object files are compiled out of c source files, but just from a logical point of view, .o files are made from .c files

Comment: Yes, `.o` files are made *from* `.c` files. So you can't understand that relationship, see `%.o: %:c` **and** mentally translate that into `to: from`. That was my point. Something in there has to give for that to be logically consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your invocation of `make`, you need to specify what you want to build, not the file you are building from.

Run make as `make test.o`

Comment: Wonderful! And please excuse my poor knowledge of make. I am still making babysteps - no pun intended